# localStorage not working with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage

I'm new to ng2 and trying to set up an auth system using Laravel as my backend and ng2 for front. I manage to get a token once signing in a user, but the code I wrote to store it with localStorage only worked once and stopped working (after I refreshed it was gone and won't set again).

**auth.service.ts:**

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Http, Headers, Response } from "@angular/http";
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import 'rxjs/Rx';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

constructor(private http: Http){

}

signup(username: string, email: string, password: string){
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user', 
        {name: username, email:email, password:password},
        {headers: new Headers({'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})});
}

signin(email: string, password: string) {

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user/signin',
        {email: email, password: password},
        {headers: new Headers({'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})})
            .map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    const token = response.json().token;
                    const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
                    const base64 = base64Url.replace('-','+').replace('_','/');
                    return {token: token, decoded: JSON.parse(window.atob(base64))};
                }
            ).do(

                tokenData => {
                    localStorage.setItem('token', tokenData.token);
                }

            );
}
}
```

**signin.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth.service';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-signin',
  templateUrl: './signin.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signin.component.css']
})
export class SigninComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private authService: AuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onSignin(form: NgForm){
    this.authService.signin(form.value.email, form.value.password)
        .subscribe(
            tokenData => console.log(tokenData),
            error => console.log(error)
        );
  }

}
```

**signin.component.html:**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSignin(f)" #f="ngForm">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" ngModel class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" ngModel class="form-control" required>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" [disabled]="!f.valid">Signin</button>
```

Comment: Is there any errors in console?

Comment: @Mr_Perfect nope, I get the token properly from the Laravel app but it doesn't save to the localStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar application but i simply used the localStorage as below:

```ts
signin(email: string, password: string) {

    return this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/api/user/signin',
        {email: email, password: password},
        {headers: new Headers({'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})})
            .map(
                (response: Response) => {
                    const token = response.json().token;
                    const base64Url = token.split('.')[1];
                    const base64 = base64Url.replace('-','+').replace('_','/');
                    localStorage.setItem('token', token);
                    return {token: token, decoded: JSON.parse(window.atob(base64))};
                }
            );
}
```

so apparently the do(){} part is never invoked.

Comment: That makes sense but I've tried it and it didn't work.. the return block works but the localStorage still doesn't. When I try running the script from incognito (chrome) I do see the variable stored in localStorage but after a refresh it disappears.

Comment: @Tom, incognito sessions should do that anyway and i am sure if that works in incognito it should work in the usual case too - so i am sure problem is not here but elsewhere!

Comment: I have also ran the code in a regular browser (not incognito) and it still clears after refresh and doesn't set again on the next trials. where else could the problem be?

Comment: review your code - you might be reseting it elsewhere. Without all of the relevant code we can only make educated guesses and not answer something definitive.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I have made some more tests with different browsers and the problem seems to occur only in chrome. Apparently, it does save the data to localStorage but for some reason it doesn't show it in the console...

Comment: No worries - glad you could isolate the issue!